Regularity of the Neumann trace
Let $\Omega$ be a Lipschitz domain with boundary $\partial \Omega$. The normal component of smooth functions on $\Omega$ is typically generalized as follows: Define the space $H(div; \Omega) = \{v \in L^2(\Omega) | div(v) \in L^2(\Omega)\}$. Then, one defines for any $\mu \in H^{1/2}(\partial \Omega)$ with lifting $\phi \in H^1(\Omega)$
$$
\int_{\partial \Omega} (v \cdot n) \mu ds := \int_\Omega v \cdot \nabla \phi dx  + \int_\Omega div(v) \phi dx,
$$
where one can show that this definition does not depend on the choice of lifting $\phi$. Hence, the above expression generalizes the normal component of smooth functions to the normal trace map $\nu_n: H(div;\Omega) \to H^{-1/2}(\partial\Omega)$, which can also be shown to be continuous.
My question is now: What further condition must be imposed on the function $v$, such that its normal trace is a function, i.e. $\nu_n(v) \in L^2(\partial\Omega)$ or with even more regularity?
I know that the normal derivative $H^{m}(\Omega) \to H^{m - 3/2}(\partial \Omega), m \geq 1$, is continuous. Is there something similar for the normal component?
